# How to make a pop back to the moreViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller

Assume that I have an application using tabbarcontroller with 10 UIViewControllers, once the UIViewController is more than 5, the Apple iPhone will generate the moreViewController for me to store rest of the UIViewController. My Question is, I want to implement a customized method to back to the more viewController, instead of using the default back in the left corner. How can I do so?

I tried with

```
[moreNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

but it seems that I have no luck. Thank you.

Comment: Try self.navigationController instead of moreNavigationController. If this isn't called from within a view controller, replace self with a variable to one of the view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of ViewControllers and then pop to the view Controller you need.

You can try this block of code

```
-(IBAction)home:(id)sender{

NSArray *array = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

}

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]